# Cakephp 3.4 - Email setTemplate() seems to be not working

Tags: cakephp-3.4

I have upgraded to Cakephp 3.4 and now doing my code migrations. I modified my email functions to the following:

```
 $email->setTemplate('welcome', 'registration')
       ->setSubject($subject)
       ->setEmailFormat('html')  
       ->setTo($toEmail)
       ->setFrom($fromEmail)
       ->send();
```

But the emails are being sent without any templates. However, if I change it back to

```
$email->template('welcome', 'registration')
```

then the emails are again sent with template. The setTemplate() function doesn't seem to be working for me. Can anybody please help me figure out what I am missing.

**Edit:**
The html file is located at 
src/Template/Email/html/welcome.ctp 
and the layout is located at 
src/Template/Layout/Email/html/registration.ctp

Comment: Is template located correctly ? Where is it ?

Comment: The `setTemplate()` method doesn't take a second argument, layouts are ment to be set via `setLayout()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses. @ndm : I tried setting the layout using setLayout() as per your suggestion and it is working. However, the [Sending Templated Emails](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#sending-templated-emails) section of the documentation describes with the example `$email->setTemplate('welcome', 'fancy')` for using layouts. We have used the above format to set the email layouts through out our application. I would like to confirm this before making the whole changes. Thanks

Comment: Those cookbook examples are definitely incorrect.

Comment: https://github.com/cakephp/docs/pull/4760

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, unlike the deprecated `Email::template()` method, which can be used to set the template as well as the layout, `Email::setTemplate()` does not take a second argument, and only sets the template.

With the newly introduced setter methods, layouts are ment to be set via the separate `Email::setLayout()` method. The examples in the Cookbook for sending templated emails were incorrect, and have now been fixed.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Email > Sending Templated Emails](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#sending-templated-emails)**
- **[API > \Cake\Mailer\Email::setTemplate()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Mailer.Email.html#_setTemplate)**
- **[API > \Cake\Mailer\Email::setLayout()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Mailer.Email.html#_setLayout)**

Answer (score -2):

/// Email format HTML

> $email->setTemplate('welcome', 'registration')
>      ->setEmailFormat('html')
>      ->setTo('bob@example.com')
>      ->setFrom('app@domain.com')
>      ->send();

This would use the following template files:

> src/Template/Email/html/welcome.ctp
>      src/Template/Layout/Email/html/registration.ctp

/// Email format TEXT

> $email->setTemplate('welcome', 'registration')
>      ->setEmailFormat('text')
>      ->setTo('bob@example.com')
>      ->setFrom('app@domain.com')
>      ->send();

This would use the following template files:

> src/Template/Email/text/welcome.ctp
>      src/Template/Layout/Email/text/registration.ctp

/// Email format BOTH

> $email->setTemplate('welcome', 'registration')
>      ->setEmailFormat('both')
>      ->setTo('bob@example.com')
>      ->setFrom('app@domain.com')
>      ->send();

This would use the following template files:

> src/Template/Email/text/welcome.ctp
>      src/Template/Layout/Email/text/registration.ctp
>      src/Template/Email/html/welcome.ctp
>      src/Template/Layout/Email/html/registration.ctp